# JMeter Test Failed-no exception printed n logs

Tags: jmeter

I am running JMeter in docker container. Here is the log. Not able to identify the reason of failure from logs. Relevant lines from log.

```
ValueReplacer.replaceValues - About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty:




JMeterThread.initRun - Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
FileServer.reserveFile - Stored: /usr/share/jmeter/bin/my.csv
JMeterThread.run - Test failed!
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB7YI.png)

What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

The logs are not "relevant" because the [stacktrace](https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/java-stack-trace-understanding/) is missing

If you take a look at [JMeter source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterThread.java#L331):

```
} catch (Exception | JMeterError e) {
    log.error("Test failed!", e);
}
```

so this `Test failed` line is followed by the extra piece of information containing what went wrong and what is the cause. We need to see it in order to be able to provide the comprehensive support

You can also [set JMeter logging verbosity to DEBUG](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) and inspect [STDOUT and STDERR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) for any suspicious entries.

Comment: That is what is troubling me, nothing is printed as exception. I just updated the question with screen shot of log.  Do you see any issues with resolving groovy variables ?